# X document overwriting the existing file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
var filename = "C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg.log";
var xmlText = new StringBuilder();
bool isXml = false;
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    if (line.Trim().StartsWith("<Message"))
        isXml = true;

    if (isXml)
    {
        xmlText.Append(line);
        if (line.Trim().EndsWith("</Message>"))
        {
            //Response.Write(xmlText.ToString());
            var xdoc= XDocument.Parse(xmlText.ToString());
            xdoc.Save("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg-2.log");
            xmlText.Clear();
            isXml = false;       
        }
    }
}
```

i am getting xml data from log file now i have a many xml tag and i am reading that tag when is read a tag i save it into file but the problem is every time my file is overwritten i want my file is not overwritten

Comment: while saving the file..append datetimenow with the file name.so each time file name will be differet..

Comment: You want to append data to `gw-msg-2.log`? Or do you want to create a new file?

Comment: no i only want to append data

Comment: @QadeerHussain .log file contain xml content? if so it can't append you have to load the file in memory modify  and then write it to disk.

Comment: no but i am getting onlyxml content from that file each time i get a tag from file and save it into another xml file but it overwrite that file

Comment: You're calling `XDocument.Save` - this serializes the XDocument object to file. It will just write the content of that object (which you're creating anew each time in your loop) into the file. As far as I know, you can't append to a file when using `XDocument.Save`. You'd be better off getting the string representation of the XDocument and appending it to your file using something like `File.AppendText` and writing to the `StreamWriter` returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var writer = File.CreateText(YOUR_FILE_NAME)))
{
  ....
  foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
  {
    ...
    //replace xdoc.Save(YOUR_FILE_NAME)
    writer.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
  }
}
```

By the way. The document you get will not be a valid XML docuemnt. It will be a series of concatinated valid XML documents.

Comment: it give me following error Token StartDocument in state End Document would result in an invalid XML document.

Comment: so what will be the solution of my problem?

Comment: Please post sample content of the files you are reading and the sample of output file you wish to get at the end, then we'll be able to help you.